# Can a contract access the code of another contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm, serpent, opcode

Using web3.js, the EVM (bytecode) of a contract can be obtained by `web3.eth.getCode(addressOfContract)`.  Can this be performed by a contract using the address of another contract?  If so, how?  [`address.code` isn't in Solidity.](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/miscellaneous.html#cheatsheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update for Solidity v0.8

You no longer have to use inline assembly to obtain the code of another contract. You can simply do it like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

function getCode(address a) public view returns (bytes memory) {
    return a.code;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The Yellow Paper mentions an EVM opcode `EXTCODECOPY` which copies an account's code to memory.  The answer appears to be yes: a contract can access the code of another contract.

Solidity `0.3.1` now provides [`extcodecopy`](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#opcodes) and other opcodes as part of its [inline assembly](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#example) feature:

> The following example provides library code to access the code of
>   another contract and load it into a bytes variable. This is not
>   possible at all with “plain Solidity” and the idea is that assembly
>   libraries will be used to enhance the language in such ways.

```
library GetCode {
  function at(address _addr) returns (bytes o_code) {
    assembly {
      // retrieve the size of the code, this needs assembly
      let size := extcodesize(_addr)
      // allocate output byte array - this could also be done without assembly
      // by using o_code = new bytes(size)
      o_code := mload(0x40)
      // new "memory end" including padding
      mstore(0x40, add(o_code, and(add(add(size, 0x20), 0x1f), bnot(0x1f))))
      // store length in memory
      mstore(o_code, size)
      // actually retrieve the code, this needs assembly
      extcodecopy(_addr, add(o_code, 0x20), 0, size)
    }
  }
}
```