# Is a race possible when checking the contract for liveness?

Tags: contract-design, security, selfdestruct

I wonder if a race is possible when performing a check of a return value of a call similar to `eth.getCode(greeter.contractAddress)` for being zero. That is, is it possible that the contract was alive during the check, but self-destructed right afterwards? I am lost with the causality rules of Ethereum.

The example call was copied from the [Contract Tutorial](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contract-Tutorial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2 cases: outside and inside the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM).**

### Outside the EVM

**Yes, race is possible if [`eth.getCode`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode) is used.**  `eth.getCode` is Javascript and is outside of a contract and the EVM.  So after `eth.getCode`, the next block that your Ethereum client receives, could have a transaction that invoked `selfdestruct` on the (greeter) contract.

### Inside the EVM

**No, if within the EVM in a single transaction,** because statements are sequential and there's currently no parallelism (as @Sebi mentions).  The EVM equivalent would be to use [`extcodesize` or `extcodecopy`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1906/can-a-contract-access-the-code-of-another-contract).  Control flow within the EVM is deterministic.

**Yes, race is possible if more than one transaction is used.**  Within the EVM, it is important to be aware that miners have full control of how transactions are ordered within a block.  Transaction Ordering Dependence (TOD) is mentioned in this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/633) and TOD contracts will usually have a security issue.  If a contract C performs `extcodesize` for contract D in *one transaction*, and then performs some action in *another transaction* (assuming that contract D still exists), then C is vulnerable to an attack: a transaction that does `selfdestruct` on D, could be inserted between the 2 transactions of C.

Answer (score 1):

No, each call to the contract is serialized (there is (currently) no parallelism in Ethereum); each node [executes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/357/does-every-node-execute-the-contract-code-for-each-transaction) a call (transaction) to the contract sequentially and then relays the result (the block containing the contract with the updated state) back to the network.