# What is the OP_CODE for getting another account (storage and/or code)?

Tags: opcode

I'm debugging solidity opcode by opcode. How do I tell when the compiler is referencing another smart contract through OpCode?

I know that you can do this in Browser Solidity. However I would just like to know the OpCode for "pointing" to data inside another contract, and how the contract's address is expressed into that opcode.

Comment: I think 0xf1 or 0xf2, see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6mRqkBz3iWcOlRem_mO09GtSKEKrAsfO7Frgx18pNU/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/can-a-contract-access-another-contracts-storage and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1906/can-a-contract-access-the-code-of-another-contract